# Is it possible to insert multiple queries in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I want to Insert the multiple queries in mysql using php form, in different tables.

Like if it is possible to use INSERT ALL command or something like this.

Provide me best path to the Problem

Comment: Please be more specific and give more details about what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you willing to have multiple actual insert statements happen though driven from one form? If so, by all means.

Comment: @DrewPierce yes you are right i wanna do same which you are talking about...

Comment: You can have 1 form submit have an impact on a ton of tables as inserts

Comment: Need to use transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean bulk insert, please follow the example given below.

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  example_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
  other_value VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO example
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

OR

if you want to insert data to multiple table, then the solution which is given below is right, write queries for each table.

Note: insert statement is written only once, we are repeating its value.

Answer (score -1):

You can add more queries like this:

```
INSERT INTO `Table` (`column`) VALUES ('theValue');
INSERT INTO `Table` (`column`) VALUES ('anotherValue');
INSERT INTO `Table` (`column`) VALUES ('yetAnotherValue');
INSERT INTO `Table` (`column`) VALUES ('theVal');
```

You can add as many queries as you like by separating them using `;`